# android ndk prebuild shared library in 64 bit

Tags: android-ndk, shared-libraries

I am working on link a pre-build shared library. I found my .so file is 64 bits and file information is shown below

```
li@cleanerSaddy:/usr/local/lib$ file libspd.so.3.0.0 
libspd.so.3.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x1148c741ed5bf3568abd82ec33187b9cf9117cf5, not stripped
```

when I run ndk-build, it gave me "incomabpatible target". shown below

```
li@cleanerSaddy:~/Projects/spd-viewer-on-android$ ndk-build
[x86] Install        : libspdio.so => libs/x86/libspdio.so
[x86] SharedLibrary  : libhello-jni.so
/home/li/Android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: error: ./obj/local/x86/libspdio.so: incompatible target
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/x86/libhello-jni.so] Error 1
```

Here is my ABI `APP_ABI := x86`.

So, how do I solve this problem in order to compile that third party library successfully?

Comment: For completeness, Android provides 64-bit now. They provided it in October 2014 with the 10c NDK. See [Developers, start your 64-bit engines](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/XG1WmNDMe8H) on the Android blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Android system is 64 bit, your library should be compiled in 32 bits, preferably with Android NDK tool chain.

Comment: Thanks, I use 32 bit VM to get 32 bit shared library

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid you're on a wrong track. You can compile a 32 bit library on a 64 bit Linux system. But in any case, you need a cross-compiler for Android. The easiest way is to use an NDK tool chain from http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know how to build now